# Uncaught type error on netlify cms admin login

Tags: jekyll, netlify, netlify-cms

I could not login my **netlify cms** admin panel, basically it's jekyll theme hosted on *Github* with custom domain.

When I click on login button it's show a following error on console

[image]

My Domain https://www.mominriyadh.me

Answer (score 2):

The NetlifyCMS config (`config.yml`) is using the Netlify `git-gateway` for authentication. In the page `admin/index.html`, you need to have the [identity widget client script](https://github.com/netlify/netlify-identity-widget) loaded prior to the `netlify-cms` script.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Content Manager</title>
  <script src="https://identity-js.netlify.com/v1/netlify-identity-widget.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Include the script that builds the page and powers Netlify CMS -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/netlify-cms@^2.0.0/dist/netlify-cms.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The script is being put in the main default layout only.